# Shortcut for switching input languages stops working after screen turns off

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, input-language

I've recently upgraded from ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 18. After the update, the shortcut `super + space` to switch input languages stopped working. It works again when I set it to something else then back to `super + space`. When the screen turns off (whether by timeout or suspending manually), the shortcut stops working again and I have to set to something else then back again. I have no idea why that happens.

If it matters, I'm using Unity and not Gnome. I find Unity's workspaces more convenient than Gnome's.

Comment: Are you using GDM or LightDM?

Comment: The result of  `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` is `/usr/sbin/gdm3`

Comment: Ok... This is really just a wild guess, but considering that you are using Unity, it may be worth to switch to LightDM. 1. Make sure that `lightdm` and `unity-greeter` are installed. 2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` 3. Reboot

Comment: That actually made it worse, lol.
Now `super + space` doesn't work at all. But `super + right alt` works with the same issue that `super + space` had before it stopped working.
`super + right alt` works until the screen turns off, then it stops working and I have to change it back and forth for it to work again.

Comment: Sorry about that. No other idea offhand.